# Modal Window load dynamic content and change it in times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy guys.

I have a modal window that loads a page and I need to, after 90 seconds load another page.

I have...

```
    <table id="table4">
    <tr>
        <td>Id:</td>
        <td>Nome:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1515</td>
        <td>Thiago</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>Guttierre</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

According to the ID, i will load a page that the id represents.. like http://www.test.com/1515. and after 90 seconds I have to load the other id... http://www.test.com/2015.

Now I have this script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//seleciona os elementos a com atributo name="modal"
var aux = 2;
while (($("#table4 tr:nth-child(" + aux + ") td:nth-child(1)") != "")) {

    var idSOS = $("#table4 tr:nth-child(" + aux + ") td:nth-child(1)").text();
    if ((idSOS != "") && (idSOS != undefined) && (idSOS != null) && (idSOS != "Id:")) {


        $("#dialog, #mask,#closediv").css({ 'display': 'block' });
        var maskHeight = "99%";
        var maskWidth = "99%";
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

        //Effect
        $('#mask').fadeIn(800);
        $("#dialog").fadeIn(1600);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $('#dialog').fadeTo("slow", 1);

        //
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        //centraliza na tela a janela popup
        $("#dialog, #mask").css('top', '2px');
        $("#dialog, #mask").css('left', '2px');

        //

        setTimeout(function() {
            var i = idSOS;
            loadContent(i);
        }, 10000);





        aux++;
        //            continue;
    } //end IF
    else {
        $("#dialog").empty();
        $("#dialog, #mask").hide();
        break;
    };


}; //END WHILE


$("#dialog, #mask").hide();

//se o botão fechar/tela for clicado
$('#closediv').click(function GetOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask,#closediv, .window').hide();
});

function loadContent(idSOS) {
    $("#dialog").load('/teste' + idSOS + '.aspx');
};
```

It only shows the second id loaded in the div. What I have to do to load the first ID loaded in the DIV "dialog" and then, after 90 seconds, show the second ID?

Where did I go wrong?

Thks folks.

Comment: Well, what happens?  What doesn't work?  You haven't described the problem.

Comment: Your logic seems off in your condition check: `(idSOS != undefined) && (idSOS != 'undefined')`. Maybe you have a reason to check for a stringified undefined. But Are you sure all conditions are passing so that the fist .load is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this happens because setTimeout expects first parameter to be a string, and you gave it a function, which is probably being executed right away

so the code should be more like:

```
setTimeout("function() { ... }", 90000);
```

however, your logic still appears to have flaws, as the "each" statement will create 2 setTimeout() functions that will both be executed at the same time after 90 seconds.

This is because it will iterate over both columns (TD) present and execute everything that is in the "each" part every time.

The code most probably needs a more detailed revision.

Comment: what if I change the each for a "while" loop?

Comment: that would produce the same result... you could try to define a variable that would hold a number of seconds and increment it each time the setTimeout is called... so for example: var time_limit = 90; $('...').each(function() { setTimeout('...', time_limit); time_limit = time_limit + 90 });

Answer (score 0):

This line is clearing the dialog right after loading it:

`$("#dialog").empty();`

Then, in the 90 second timeout, it loads the second item successfully.

Comment: Man.. it isn't the problem. If it was, the page would be displayed, then nothing appear and before 90 seconds another page would be displayed again. I put this line to do a test and forgot to remove.